# How to prevent Laravel queue job, schedule and cron job from killing the server

Tags: php, laravel, cron

My problem is more of fallback I think, now I have a two queue job in my Laravel job queue, and I am using database Driver. The first command create credentials for my user from another site base on API calls, and the second is to email for verification and 2FA. Also, there is another command that update change my unit conversion rate.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
$schedule->command('update:conversionRate')->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute(); 
}
```

Queue job are added to my queue using dispatch command and shouldQueue interface the API call uses the dispatch function while the email uses shouldQueue.

Now it work because I can see the jobs in my database. But when the server cron job runs it will crash, and my Log file shows that the my MySQL users has reach it maximum connection limit. Hence nobody can assess the database using that user account.

So my question how do I setup the cron job and `queue:work` so that it does not crash the server?

Comment: You're using queue the wrong way. And once queue works (queue:work), you don't need to execute to make it work again. Use beanstalkd to make sure your queues are always run.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You'd need to find out why your connection limit has been reached. How many connections does a single instance of the cron job take? Are you running a loop and then opening connections inside of the loop, rather than opening one connection outside of it?

Answer (score 1):

How I understood your problem with the maximum connection to the database.

The first solution, but it is not best to increase the connection limit to the database.

The second solution is to work with the queue. You have not tried to use a driver not a database, for example redis or beanstalkd?

You also run the command every minute. It's a bad practice to use cron job for queues. There is a supervisor for this.

Also, with the team, try to use the queue: work parameters.

**Example**

```
php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
```

--sleep this handler will have a break between the processing of the elements of the queue

--tries = 3 if for some reason the item will not be processed, after this parameter it will try 3 times and proceed to the next element, where by default it will try to try many times.

Experiment with these options.

Comment: I ask my server provide if they can install supervisor. the answer is no because of it is a shared Host.

Comment: @AdajOEL You do not need to run every minute. Run this command once